# Python Pandas Where Condition Is Not Working

Tags: pandas, where-clause

I have created a where condition with python.

```
filter = data['Ueber'] > 2.3
data[filter]
```

Here you can see my dataset.

```
   Saison  Spieltag            Heimteam  ... Ueber  Unter  UeberUnter
0    1819         3      Bayern München  ...  1.30   3.48       Ueber
1    1819         3       Werder Bremen  ...  1.75   2.12       Unter
2    1819         3         SC Freiburg  ...  2.20   1.69       Ueber
3    1819         3       VfL Wolfsburg  ...  2.17   1.71       Ueber
4    1819         3  Fortuna Düsseldorf  ...  1.46   2.71       Ueber
```

Unfortunately, my greater than condition is not working. What's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hallo. Have you checked the datatypes already? What colum type is Über? For me it worked, when I imported your data with `read_csv` and letting it figure out the types itself. I really suspect, that there is something wrong with the types in your dataframe, but on the other hand, if it was string, an exception should be raised.

Comment: Datatype is decimal or number.

Comment: what does `data.dtypes` say?

Comment: Sorry, it is float64.

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't make a difference, it should work. and `print(data[data['Ueber']>2.3])` _really_ prints the table you listed above?

Comment: Empty DataFrame Index: []

Comment: This sounds highly unlikely.

Comment: print(data[data['Spieltag']== 3]) this is working

Comment: No, that is exactly, what should happen! The result dataframe should be empty, because there are no such rows. I guess there is a misunderstanding here. If you create an indexer (that is what the guy in variable `filter` is called), and you then execute `data[filter]`, it doesn't change the dataframe or restrict it permanently. It just returns a filtered dataframe. You have to assign it to a variable, otherwise it is gone after the line was executed.

Comment: Just like, if you have a line in your python code like `3+4`. It will do the addition, but nobody will ever see it, because it immediately diaspears.

Comment: You absolutly right. Of course, there is no data greater than 2,3, Thanks it works.

Comment: Maybe you overrated the abilities of the "1. FC Bayern München". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of clarity, if you have really floats into your column, which you want into conditional check then it should work.

### Example DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [-12.5, 60.0, 50.0, -25.10, 50.0, 51.0, 71.0]} , dtype=float)

>>> df
    num
0 -12.5
1  60.0
2  50.0
3 -25.1
4  50.0
5  51.0
6  71.0
```

Conditional check to compare..

```
>>> df['num'] > 50.0
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
Name: num, dtype: bool
```

### Result:

```
>>> df [ df['num'] > 50.0 ]
    num
1  60.0
5  51.0
6  71.0
```